# Is it possible to avoid overhead while using boost_any?

Tags: c++, boost, casting, boost-any

I'd like to use `boost::any` as a universal type to store in a container and to pass to different functions. But inside these functions I always know the real type, so in runtime I don't need any type safety checks and the imposed overhead, `static_cast` is enough.

The ideal solution would be to use something like `boost::polymorphic_downcast`, but as I can see it can't be applied in this case.

Should I just write my own wrapper for `void*` or is there another option?

Comment: If you know the types at compile time anyway, why need `boost::any`? Can't you use a struct containing all the types you need an put that in a container?

Comment: @TonyTheLion: Whouldn't that be terribly memory-inefficient?

Comment: If it's really true that `any` is the right type *and* you always know the actual type, then you could make a container of void pointers...

Comment: where are you loosing type of your container? Maybe you should not do that?

Comment: Because it's choosen in runtime what type is needed and what is not, and I also would prefer not to change the code for this global container in case I would need another type.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use template container?

Comment: Also if you will put your container into `boost::any` it will devrease overhead

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I suppose that depends on what types you have and how you arrange them in your struct.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `shared_ptr<void>` or unique_ptr with `static_cast` to replace `boost::any`, `shared_ptr<void>` has several advantage over raw `void*` pointer like:

- automatically delete its storage
- can referenced by multiple object in your code(may be you don't need this)

But of course in this case you need more memory for every pointer(for reference counting and deleter).

if sharing is not good for you and your object will only owned in container you may also use `unique_ptr<void>`.